# MongoError: collection name must be a String

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting " MongoError: collection name must be a String" while trying to get data through post. Here is error which I am getting:-

```
"
MongoError: collection name must be a String
    at checkCollectionName (/home/rishabh/test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:99:11)
    at new Collection (/home/rishabh/test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:101:3)
    at Db.collection (/home/rishabh/test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:335:26)
    at Object.queries.getPlayersList (/home/rishabh/test/dbConnection/queries.js:207:24)
    at playersList (/home/rishabh/test/lib/MonthlyLeaderboard.js:38:11)
    at /home/rishabh/test/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:760:23
    at /home/rishabh/test/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
    at fn (/home/rishabh/test/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
    at /home/rishabh/test/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
    at /home/rishabh/test/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37

"
```

Here is code line number :-

```
queries.getPlayersList = function(collectionName, query, callback) {
db().db('test').collection(collectionName).find(query.id).sort(query.sortBy).skip(query.skip).limit(parseInt(query.limit) ).toArray(function (err, result) {

        callback(err, result);
    })
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: can you post your DB connection initialisation code

Comment: connection.init = function init(callback) {
    console.log(url);
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Not Created!');
            callback(err)
        } else {
            callback(null);
            createColl(db);
            dbConnection.db = db;
            console.log('Database Created!');
        }
    });
};

Comment: This means that it's not a string, simple as that. Currently you're the only person who can debug the piece of code where `getPlayersList` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Taking connection url to be like below where **test** is the **Database** you are connecting to:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/test
```

In connection code db instance is stored as

```
dbConnection.db = db;
```

To find do following:

```
dbConnection.db.collection(CollectionName).find(query).sort(sortBy).toArray((err, docs) => {
    console.log('----docs----', docs);
})
```